# How to split string in elixir keeping separators?

Tags: elixir

I have a String with special characters:

```
>> text = "ab()-cdef"
```

I want to separate the letters from the special characters in a list

```
>> list = ["ab", "(" , ")" ,"-", "cdef"]
```

I tried with

```
list = String.split(text,["(",")","-"], trim: false)
```

But I lose the special characters

```
list = ["ab","","","","cdef"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there. Use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split the string on non-letters.

```rb
String.split "ab()-cdef", ~r/(?<=\W)|(?=\W)/
#⇒ ["ab", "(", ")", "-", "cdef"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for Regex.split](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#split/3) mentions the `:include_captures` option:

```rb
iex> Regex.split(~r{(x)}, "Elixir", include_captures: true)
["Eli", "x", "ir"]

iex> Regex.split(~r{a(?<second>b)c}, "abc", on: [:second], include_captures: true)
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Note that when [String.split](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/String.html#split/3) is used with a regular expression you can use this option as well.

Answer (score 1):

I used `Regex.scan/2`.

```
~r{\(|\)|-|[a-z]*}
|> Regex.scan("ab()-cdef")
|> List.flatten()
|> Enum.filter(fn s -> String.length(s) > 0 end)
```

I had to escape some special characters -- for example, `(` became `\(` -- and separate special characters with pipes.